# Bluetooth server From Mac to android

Tags: java, android, macos, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm looking to set up a bluetooth server in java to receive string from an android bluetooth client.

I've read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929767/send-text-through-bluetooth-from-java-server-to-android-client), but the bluecove library seems to have trouble under Mac OS X Since 10.8 and it's not resolved yet...

So, my question is : do you which way would be the better to set up a bluetooth server with Java on Mac OS X ?